# Azure Static website on Storage Account behind Application Gateway

Tags: azure, proxy, gateway

Since a some time I'm trying to configure app gateway to serve Static Website in subfolder of main domain.
I have already app gateway configured, which handling already two applications (app services).
On Backend pool I have two applications defined and the all rewrites are made like that:

[www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) --> production app service
[www.domain.com/test](http://www.domain.com/test) --> test app service

But now I want to setup something like this:
[www.domain.com/staticsite](http://www.domain.com/staticsite) --> static website on storage account

How to do that? what rewrite rules should I use?

In current configuration I have:
Rule:
[image]

Rewrites:
[image]
[image]
[image]

How Rewrite should looks like? because if I add another one, same as for /test, I got 504 bad gateway error. For the moment, access to static page is unlimited.